# Images will not attach to posts after site migration

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, migration

I recently migrated a WordPress install from a subdirectory to the root. After the migration everything worked great, except that I can no longer set a featured thumbnail or add a picture in the WYSIWYG. On a possibly related note, I can only set post tags from the Quick Edit screen and not the post edit screen.

When I click set featured image on the post edit screen it opens the screen to add media, but it opens in a new page, not like in a box before. When I click to the media library and click show next to an image, it does not show and so I can't select "use as featured image." I can still upload the photo, but I can't attach it to the post.

I'm not sure if the tags issue is related, but whenever I enter a tag in the Post Tag box it will not save. But if I go out to the All Posts listing, I can enter them via Quick Edit.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be javascript errors. Do you have any js errors showing up in firebug console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a jQuery conflict. I deregistered the default jQuery in WordPress to use the Google CDN version. Works great on the front-end, but it was messing up the admin. Wrapped it in an !is_admin() if statement and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your media upload path in the admin.
2. verify  that your DB has NO references to the old domain 
   (I am sure you have done so already, but I will post it anyhow)
   when you do that , include the last trailing slash.

// update WordPress options ,  SQL command:

```
  UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

// fix URLs of the WordPress posts and pages, SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');
```

// SQL commands to fix all internal links

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

1. if that is not helping, disable all plugins (and custom function - functions.php) , remove all custom JS files, and try again .